# GCC - display preprocessed value during preprocessing

Tags: gcc, preprocessor-directive

Is there a way to make GCC display the value of some preprocessed value during preprocessing? In particular, if I run the equivalent of:

```
gcc input.c -E >/dev/null
```

Is there a way to obtain the actual value of an expanded macro? Consider this example:

```
#if defined(A)
#define B bar
#else
#define B foo
#endif

#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x

int main() {
#pragma message "B is " XSTR(B)
#error DIE
  B a = 2;
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to find out that `B is foo` in this case.

In my actual setup, I do not have access to the entirely preprocessed file, and I cannot remove the `-E` flag.

Rationale: I have a complex file setup with lots of syntax errors due to incorrectly defined macros, and the fastest way to debug it would be to use this `#pragma/#error` combination to find out the actual value, stop compilation, manually fix it, and run GCC again to find out where the next error will occur.